# VueJS + HighChartJS : Synchronization of columns data with chart

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vue-component, vuetify.js

How to render the table data and display this using HighChartJS, I am not able to render this. As the number of active columns is visible the different graphs should be displayed and dynamically change data.

My code is

```html
<template>
<div class="DatabaseTable">
  <Navbar></Navbar>
  <v-app>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      DataVisualisation
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="info"
      :search="search"
      :items-per-page="5"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
       <td>{{ props.item.Date }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.item.location }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.item.type }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.item.percent }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.item.length_max }}</td>
     </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
  </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getAPI } from '../axios-api'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Vuetify_DatabaseTable_search',
  data () {
    return {
      search:'',
      headers: [
      {text: 'Date', value: 'Date'},
      {text: 'Location', value: 'location'},
      {text: 'Type', value: 'type'},
      {text: 'Percent(%)', value: 'percent'},
      {text: 'Length max', value: 'length_max'},
      ],
      info: []
    }
  },
  components:{
            Navbar
        },
  mounted () {

      getAPI.get('datavisualisation/summary')
      .then(response => {
        let resdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        let respdata = response.data
        console.log(resdata)
        console.log(respdata)
      })
  }
};
</script>
```

sometimes, I will be having nested array of JSON, which will be difficult to render to table, how this type of data can be displayed in table and in Highchart.

The response data, that I am getting from the back end.
[image: resdata]

[image: respdata]

**Ungrouped Graph**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option would be to store data in the *App.vue* component and pass this data to the chart and table component separately.

Then if data changes, the table, and the chart will change too. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-9oc4v?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Okay, but I am getting the data using API from the backend (Django) and this will be in the object, how this can be converted to table and chart format respectively. So, dynamic changes in the table affect the graph.

Comment: When I tried the demo code in my project, I got 3 errors:
** Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "chartData". Expected Object, got Array

** Unknown custom element: <highcharts> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

** Missing required prop: "chartData"

Comment: You can pass the data to the App.vue component in the place of chartData in my demo. Whenever it gets changed there it'll change both the content of the table and the chart. Sorry for the errors, probably I forgot to fork the demo to the latest version. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-fdrom?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank you, your demo code is working now, but when I change it with my API data as you mentioned, the Table is being displayed as expected ( before also it was getting displayed) but in the chart, nothing is popping. It's a blank chart. for example, I have 9 data columns, in which date has to be on X-axis and counts on Y-axis.

Comment: To be honest it is hard to tell you what could be done without taking look at your code. Do you have any errors? In what format is your data? Does point contain x and y coordinates?

Comment: I don't have separate x and y coordinates. The response data I am getting from the backend has 7 columns. I need to draw a line and bar graphs out of these columns. The x coordinates will be a date, and for y coordinates, it will be length columns or def_percent or counts. The graph needs to be drawn based on location.
I have updated my question with the response data images. Please suggest to me how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the images! I've prepared a simple demo presenting how we could parse your data to the chart and the table. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-dj2c7?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updates, I am able to pass one column at a time now, is there a way to send multiple column at the same time? and the graph, how can that be grouped according to other columns(say Tank 1). I have attached the graph, I am able to draw, it is not as expected.

Comment: If you want to send multiple series you just need to modify the code that I wrote in the last demo. Just prepare a couple of data arrays and create a variable that will store an array of series objects. Put the data arrays into each object of the created variable like that: let series = [{ data: parsedData1 }, { data: parsedData2 }]; Then send a series variable to the Chart.vue and Table.vue like before.

Comment: But, as you can see, the graph, the data is not groped and it doesn't seem like a line chart.

Comment: Maybe something in your settings is not right. Unfortunately, it's hard to say what's wrong because you didn't provide me your demo.

Comment: Please find the demo code https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-ramanujan-uk65w?file=/src/App.vue:2178-2193 In the demo, the graph is weirder.

Comment: Thanks for that! The chart looks this way because your data is not sorted. As far as I see you have multiple points with the same x coordinate. Only one of them could be hovered. How would you like the chart to look like with a lot of points with the same x coordinate?

Comment: There is one more column called location, based on that, I would like to get the chart, I mean to say, 6 different lines grouped by location and spread across the dates in X-coordinate.